# Dual GM and Player RPGs

Tags: game-recommendation, one-on-one, round-robin-gming

I've played a few RPGs with the classical X amount of players and one GM.
However sometimes this can be hard/not enjoyable to play especially if nobody wants to solely be the GM, and usually the person that takes on the role as GM is stuck with it, even for later, unrelated adventures/games simply because they are the "best" at it. (Perhaps this is just bad RPG playing methods?).
So my question is, is there any RPGs out there that implement dual players and GMs? Where in a two player game/adventure, both players are GMs for each other's worlds. For example, player A plays adventure 1 while player B plays adventure 2, but player A is the GM for adventure 2 and player B is the GM for adventure 1.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Please take the [tour] to get to know how we do things around here Unfortunately, I think your question is going to be closed, as 'shopping' questions are not something that works well in the strictly Q&A format. We do have a [list of recommended forums](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/16370) that you can seek such advice from.

Comment: Off topic close does not mean "answer in comments."

Comment: I've added the [tag:one-on-one] tag to this question. Perusing other questions in that tag may be helpful to you, and perhaps you can ask more specific, Stack-friendly questions based on that information. And when you've got 20+ rep, feel free to join the [chat]!

Comment: @BESW That was the topic I was looking for! I didn't know the terminology for that. That tag is very useful